# Flutter: How to update the list after deleting the list on click on button

Tags: flutter, android-listview, builder, listviewitem

I am trying to delete the specific list when click on button, it is deleted but my it duplicate the last value of list, let say if list length is 4 and I deleted the 1 item, it delete that but the last item of list appeared again, it means it duplicate the last item.

here is my code

```
//created the method to delete this list item
 void _deleteItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      historyList.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 70, 0, 0),
            child:  FutureBuilder(
                  future: _getRecord(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<List<leaveHistory>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     if(historyList.length!=0){
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
                        child:Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        subtitle:Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                         children: [
                         Text("Date: "+snapshot.data[index].date,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                            FlatButton(
                            child: Text("Approved",),
                            onPressed: (){
                            _deleteItem(index);     //called method here
                             }
```

`_getRecord()` is a method where i am fetching data from api and adding it into `historyList`

kindly help where i am doing wrong

Comment: You actually deleting the object from the history list but you also need to remove the item from snapshot.data list.

Comment: Or else you can assign the snapshot.data to historylist using the setState method and the remove the item which may work cause the building and displaying list will be same then.

Comment: is this u are trying to say ```setState(() { snapshot.data.remove(index);  });``` adding this line after the method calling?

Comment: Yes something like this...

Comment: but it is not working!